# What hardware components do not require driver and why

Tags: kernel, drivers

This is a question that I had in my mind long ago but just now resurfaced back after reading this [article](https://knowstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/06/11/linux-kernel-and-architecture/).

May I know why CPU and memory do not require driver? What other hardware components do not require driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *driver* is a translation software that sits between the hardware and the Operating System and perform multiple tasks as : control of I/O operations, initialization and configuration of the hardware device.

Your Operating System doesn't need a driver for the CPU because it has been  compiled to work with a determined CPU.

For example Debian has the following "*flavors*":

- *amd64*: x86-64 architecture with 64-bit userland and supporting 32-bit software
- *arm64*: ARMv8-A architecture
- *armel*: Little-endian ARM architecture (ARMv4T instruction set) on various embedded systems (EABI)
- *armhf*: ARM hard-float architecture (ARMv7 instruction set) requiring hardware with a floating-point unit
- *i386*: IA-32 architecture with 32-bit userland, compatible with x86-64 machines
- *mips*: Big-endian MIPS architecture
- *mipsel*: Little-endian MIPS architecture
- *powerpc*: PowerPC architecture
- *ppc64el*: Little-endian PowerPC64 architecture supporting POWER7+ and POWER8 CPUs
- *s390x*: z/Architecture with 64-bit userland, intended to replace s390

If you try to install a Debian compiled for *PowerPC* in an *Intel* hardware, it won't work.

Usually the hardware that needs drivers is the one that interacts with the outside world (video cards, sound cards, modems, LAN and wireless cards) because manufacturers are constantly releasing new products that obsolete the old ones in terms of features, speed, etc. It means a wide span of hardware in the market each one with its own chipset, features and configuration parameters and with its own driver.

Answer (score 1):

Many USB devices do not need specific drivers since they are fully compliant to a predefined specification: flash drive, audio controller, audio input, etc. I can't direct you to a detailed documentation about that, but searching "usb class" may be a start.

Sometimes, a specific driver is provided, but the device can still work without it. In that case, the driver is only here to enable additionnal features (I saw it for instance on an external hard drive and a MIDI controlers).